# AJAX Toolkit - AsyncFileUpload Control Return Data

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using the AsyncFileUpload control provided by the Ajax Toolkit. I am needing to store the file uploaded in a temporary directory and then return the temporary file name back to the client (or set viewstate) so that on the next post back it can be committed to a database.

Does anyone have any ideas as the best approach to do this, if even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.
OnClientUploadComplete is fired on the client-side after the upload has completed. Then just use get_fileName() to return the name of the file being uploaded.

Example:
function uploadCompleted(sender, args) 
{
  alert(args.get_fileName());
}